# Batch Request return An unknown error occurred when try to create adgroups

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, ads

I use batch request for complete operations. I send 50 operations for update and its return success there is not problem. But if i make a batch request more than 15 for create new adgroup its return array ;
Array
(
    [error_code] => 1
    [error_msg] => An unknown error occurred
)

But i checked my ads panel every operation is completed! its returned error but did my operations also. So i dont know new adgroups ids.

I try also if i limit to 15 of batch operation count, everything is going good not problem. So problem is when batch request more than 15 return value has mistake. I think its bug.

I use last php sdk.

How can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue with the API; large batches of create calls for ads often fail due to timeouts - see this bug report for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/208797482578964

lower your call rate and it should be OK